# Как лучше писать и редактировать свой код, если команда работает через Git Lab и тестовый сайт залит в его репозиторий?

Tags: git, gitlab, скрипт, проверка

Только начал изучение Git Lab. Не нашел, как ни странно, ответы на следующие вопросы:

1. В случае, если тестовый сайт на Git Lab, как пишется и проверяется код? Все равно на локальном сервере, вроде Open Server, с установленной на него копией сайта локально? Потом проверенные на работоспособность скрипты git push-ем направляются в Git Lab?
2. Как "закомиченный" код из Git Lab попадает на хостинг или выделенный сервер.. В команде обычно есть человек, который отправляет?

Answer (score 2):

1. От того, находится ли код на gitlab или github, то как Вы пишите код и как его тестируете не меняется. Вы можете продолжать пользоваться своими любимыми инструментами. Главное не забывать "пушить" готовые фичи.
2. да, такой человек может быть и называется build engenier или devops. В самом простом случае просто копируют скрипты на сервер и готово (но так делать не модно и на больших кодовых базах могут быть проблемы).  Сейчас модно использовать CI/CD системы с докерами и kubernetes. И когда все настроено, то деплой - это просто нажать одну кнопку.

- Пример деплоя с gilab в aws https://habr.com/ru/company/softmart/blog/310502/
- Ещё один пример выкладывания сайта https://medium.com/@cakeinpanic/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-ci-%D0%BD%D0%B0-gitlab-19489cc79fe8